# Intuition for MaybeT

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers

I'm trying to understand `MaybeT` by running a few examples in `ghci`:

```
λ: import Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe
λ: let x = return $ 42 :: MaybeT (Either String) Int
λ: :t x
x :: MaybeT (Either String) Int
```

Then, I ran it:

```
λ: runMaybeT x
Right (Just 42)
```

Please give me value, `y`, such that

```
runMaybeT y === Left (Just "...")
runMaybeT y === Left Nothing
runMaybeT y === Right Nothing
```

Answer (score 3):

You will never get a `Left Nothing` or `Left (Just ..)`, as the monad here is `Either String …`, so that in the left you will always have a `String`.

Here is what you can get:

```
> let y = fail "Failed" :: MaybeT (Either String) Int
> runMaybeT y
Right Nothing
> let y = lift (Left "Failed") :: MaybeT (Either String) Int
> runMaybeT y
Left "Failed"
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help gain some insight into what's going on underneath the hood with MaybeT...

In the IO monad we have computations, e.g.

```
putStrLn "Hello, world!" :: IO ()
getContents :: IO String
```

etc. All of these computations have type `IO a`, and in fact the type variable `a` is unrestricted - it can be any type. Using `return` we can create an IO computation `IO a` for any type `a`.

***You can think of `MaybeT IO` as being those IO computations which return a Maybe value.***

For instance, `getContents` is an `IO` computation but not a `MaybeT IO` computation. However, there is a kinda obvious way to convert `getContents` into a `MaybeT IO` computation -- simply wrap its output in the `Just` constructor:

```
lift getContents   ===   fmap Just getContents
```

`lift` is the way to promote an `IO` computation to a `MaybeT IO` computation. Applying this to `return_IO` (the `return` function for the `IO` monad) we have:

```
return_(MaybeT IO) === lift return_IO === fmap Just return_IO
```

That is, `return 3` (in the `MaybeT IO` monad) is the same as `return (Just 3)` in the `IO` monad.

***runMaybeT and MaybeT are inverses of each other***

Now have a look at the [definition of `MaybeT`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.2.0/docs/src/Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe.html#MaybeT)

```
newtype MaybeT m a = MaybeT { runMaybeT :: m (Maybe a) }
```

This also describes the idea that computations in `MaybeT m` are the same as computations in `m` which return a Maybe value. The functions:

```
MaybeT    :: m (Maybe a) -> MaybeT m a
runMaybeT :: MaybeT m a  -> m (Maybe a)
```

are inverses of each other and don't really do anything except add or remove the newtype wrapper. In the case of the `IO` monad:

```
MaybeT    :: IO (Maybe a) -> MaybeT IO a
runMaybeT :: MaybeT IO a  -> IO (Maybe a)
```

Considering the example in your question, we see that computations in `MaybeT (Either String)` are essentially the same as values of type `Either String (Maybe a)` for any type `a`. This leads to the following possibilities:

- `Left` of some string
- `Right (Just ...)`
- `Right Nothing`

These all exist in `Either String (Maybe a)`, and if we apply the constructor `MaybeT` to each of them we get the corresponding values in `MaybeT (Either String) a`.

In particular, to find a `y` s.t.

```
runMaybeT y == Right Nothing
```

just use:

```
          y = MaybeT (Right Nothing)
```

Again, `runMaybeT` and `MaybeT` are inverses of each other, so you can arrive at the same result by applying `MaybeT` to both sides.